# cron job to find a file and list its output if found

Tags: linux

I am trying to get a cron job setup to run every 10 mins to find 2 particular file(lets say a and b)  and if found cat its output and the timestamp when the file was created and send it as an email in suse linux.

could anyone please suggest .

Thank you
 Jonu Joy

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that mail-delivery as such works, and that you know how to edit crontabs ...

Put the following into a script (modify paths to match your system, I don't have suse here to play with), make it executable, and run that from cron every ten minutes.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name a -o -name b|while read file; do ls -l $file; cat $file; echo "" ; done | mail user@domain
```

And then:

```
chmod +x /path/to/script/above
```

Run from cron like so:

```
0/10 * * * * /path/to/script/above
```